# How do I get the server logs for a Rails 4 application in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am using Devise and it sends out a confirmation email when a new user account is created. Since I am in development, in `localhost`, it doesn't really send out the email, so I just copy the confirmation link from the server info that appears on the console.

The thing is, as one particular page grew, the amount of information that the server processes after the email is sent became too large for the terminal, the backscroll ends before I reach the link. I checked `/log/development.log` but it logs other things. I studied the config and debug parts of the rails doc but I couldn't find anything about server logging.

So now I have no way of copying the confirmation link from the console, and no way of confirming new accounts, which I still need to do since it is part of the proposed flow.

How can I get the server logs?

Comment: One thing you might want to include in your application is the `quiet_assets` gem. I include this on every one of my projects and it cuts down the log output quite a bit. Might be a good place to start at least

Comment: The email content should be in the dev log?try 'cat /dev/null > log/development.log' and then try it, should make it easier to find

Comment: Also you might want to checkout - https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Comment: @house9 Weird, the real problem was that it wasn't displaying the email content on the logs, it just said "sent mail to [address]", so I didn't catch it before because I was looking for the layout of the content. I have no idea how or why this started to happen. However, I installed letter_opener and it worked perfectly so for now this is a non-issue. Thanks!